# Converge in distribution and order of convergence

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, central-limit-theorem

I have read an econometrics textbook on "converge in distribution" and found the following sentence.

\begin{equation}
  Z_{N} \xrightarrow{d} Z\implies Z_{N} = {O_p}(1)  
\end{equation}
That is, if a random variable $Z_n$ converges in distribution to $Z$, $Z_N$ is bounded in probability.
The textbook states that this is easy to verify. However, I cannot figure it out at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show $Z_n=O_p(1)$, that is, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist $n_\epsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_\epsilon>0$, such that $P(|Z_n| > a_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ for all $n>n_\epsilon$.

To do this, let's first find a point $z>0$ at which $F_Z$ is continuous and $F_Z(-z) + 1-F_Z(z)<\epsilon/2$.

Now because of convergence in distribution, there exists $n_\epsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $F_{Z_n}(-z) + 1-F_{Z_n}(z)<\epsilon$.

The last equation means $P(|Z_n| > z) < \epsilon$. Thus, we have found the bound $a_\epsilon>0$ and proved the result.

Comment: Minor note: you need "for all $n>n_\epsilon$" in   your definition of $O_p$

Comment: @ThomasLumley Yes. I've fixed the typo. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you both of u!

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Thanks for spotting that typo. Let me fix that!